# How to count check-boxes using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, count, checked

I have tons of checkboxes that are either checked (`checked="checked"`) or unchecked.

I would like to get the number of all checkboxes, unchecked and checked checkboxes.

With check-box I mean `<input type="checkbox" />`.

How can this be done with jQuery?

Answer (score 179, accepted):

You could do:

```
var numberOfChecked = $('input:checkbox:checked').length;
var totalCheckboxes = $('input:checkbox').length;
var numberNotChecked = totalCheckboxes - numberOfChecked;
```

EDIT

Or even simple

```
var numberNotChecked = $('input:checkbox:not(":checked")').length;
```

Answer (score 19):

Assume that you have a tr row with multiple checkboxes in it, and you want to count only if the first checkbox is checked.

You can do that by giving a class to the first checkbox

**For example** `class='mycxk'` and you can count that using the filter, like this

```
$('.mycxk').filter(':checked').length
```

Comment: I prefer this answer in my case because I can define the `let myCheckboxList = $('.mycxk');` to reuse it after this `myCheckboxList.filter(':checked').length`.

Comment: I also liked this answer

Comment: this answer is good, i want count input with class :))

Answer (score 18):

The following code worked for me.

```
$('input[name="chkGender[]"]:checked').length;
```

Answer (score 6):

There are multiple methods to do that:

**Method 1:**

```
alert($('.checkbox_class_here:checked').size());
```

**Method 2:**

```
alert($('input[name=checkbox_name]').attr('checked'));
```

**Method 3:**

```
alert($(":checkbox:checked").length);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using name attibute, class, id or just universal checkbox;
If you want to count only *checked* number of checkbox.

By the class name :

```js
var countChk = $('checkbox.myclassboxName:checked').length;
```

By name attribute :

```js
var countByName= $('checkbox[name=myAllcheckBoxName]:checked').length;
```

### Complete code

```js
$('checkbox.className').blur(function() {
    //count only checked checkbox 
    $('checkbox[name=myAllcheckBoxName]:checked').length;
});
```