# Count number of selected checkboxes and display value in appropriate position

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, counter

I would like to count the number of selected checkboxes from a list, and then display the number of checkboxes selected next to the corresponding divs. Ie if the user selects 3 option from the Dogs list, 2 from the Birds list and 1 from the reptile list the 'x' next to the buttons get replaced by 3, 2, and 1 respectively, rather than getting 6 next to Dogs, as I am currently getting.     I have tried to follow this question [How to count every checked checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725969/jquery-how-to-count-every-checked-checkboxes/)

**JS fiddle example**

https://jsfiddle.net/j2dypbhc/8/

**HTML**

```
<div id="type1" class="type">
    <h3>1.2 Select material v1</h3>

    <span id="value">x</span>
    <button class="bob" type="button" name="material" value="1">Dogs</button>

    <span id="value">x</span>
    <button class="bob" type="button" name="material" value="2">Birds</button>                  

    <span id="value">x</span>
    <button class="bob" type="button" name="material" value="3">Reptiles</button>                       
</div>
<div id="material1" class="material">
    <input  class="select_all" type="checkbox" name="tile[]" value="1">Pugs
    <input  class="select_all" type="checkbox" name="tile[]" value="2">Boxer
    <input clas="select_all" type="checkbox" name="tile[]" value="3">Dalmation
</div>
<div id="material2" class="material">
    <input  class="select_all" type="checkbox" name="tile[]" value="4">Eagle
    <input  class="select_all" type="checkbox" name="tile[]" value="5">Swan
    <input clas="select_all" type="checkbox" name="tile[]" value="6">Budgie
</div>
<div id="material3" class="material">
    <input  class="select_all" type="checkbox" name="tile[]" value="7">Snake
    <input  class="select_all" type="checkbox" name="tile[]" value="8">Lizard
    <input clas="select_all" type="checkbox" name="tile[]" value="9">Iguana
</div>
```

Comment: On click of what it should count ???

Comment: On click it should count the number of checkboxes selected.  I have made it that far.  The issue I am having is to separate the count by type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's would work for you ) Also i've removed some typo in your html.

```js
$(".select_all").change(function(){
  var selectedTypeCount = $("input[name='" + $(this).attr('name') + "']:checked").length;
  $("[id*=" + $(this).attr('name') + "]").html(selectedTypeCount);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="type1" class="type"><h3>1.2 Select material v1</h3>
                            <span id="dogsCount">x</span><button class="bob" type="button" name="material" value="1">Dogs</button>
                            <span id="birdsCount">x</span><button  class="bob" type="button" name="material" value="2">Birds</button>                    <span id="reptilesCount">x</span><button  class="bob" type="button" name="material" value="3">Reptiles</button>                       </div>


              <div id="material1" class="material">
                            <input  class="select_all" type="checkbox" name="dogs" value="1">Pugs
                            <input  class="select_all" type="checkbox" name="dogs" value="2">Boxer
                            <input class="select_all" type="checkbox" name="dogs" value="3">Dalmation
                        </div>
                        <div id="material2" class="material">
                                <input  class="select_all" type="checkbox" name="birds" value="4">Eagle
                            <input  class="select_all" type="checkbox" name="birds" value="5">Swan
                            <input class="select_all" type="checkbox" name="birds" value="6">Budgie
                        </div>
                        <div id="material3" class="material">
                            <input  class="select_all" type="checkbox" name="reptiles" value="7">Snake
                            <input  class="select_all" type="checkbox" name="reptiles" value="8">Lizard
                            <input class="select_all" type="checkbox" name="reptiles" value="9">Iguana
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you have many duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid. You should change these to classes.

The actual you have issue is because the logic in the `updateCounter()` function is flawed. You need to count only the checked boxes within the `.material` div which is related to the button which showed them. You then need to traverse the DOM to find the related `.value` element and update its `text()`. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".bob").click(function() {
        var divname = this.value;
        $(this).addClass("active")
        $("#material" + divname).show().siblings('.material').hide();
    });
    $('#value').text('');

    $("#general-content input:checkbox").on("change", updateCounter);
})

function updateCounter() {
    var $material = $(this).closest('.material');
    var $value = $(".value").eq($material.index('.material'));
    var len = $material.find("input[name='tile[]']:checked").length;
    $value.text(len > 0 ? '(' + len + ')' : 'x');
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/j2dypbhc/10/)

Comment: No problem, glad to help.