# Detect if checkbox is clicked or not using form wizard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, formwizard

I am currently using a form wizard:

```
<form name="example-1" id="wrapped" action="" method="POST">
     <div id="middle-wizard">
           <div class="step">
           </div>
           <div class="step">
           </div>
           <div class="step">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                         <ul class="data-list-2 clearfix">
                               <li><input name="information[]" id ="other_info" class="otherInfo check_radio" type="checkbox"  value="Others"><label>Others</label></li>
                         </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
     </div>


<div id="bottom-wizard">
            <button type="button" name="backward" class="backward"> Backward </button>
            <button type="button" name="forward" class="forward"> Forward </button>
</div>
</form>
```

I am trying to check if the checkbox is checked or not. First thing I did was to console log the id of the checkbox.

The console returns the checkbox but when I tried to create a click function on the checkbox id, the on click function doesn't throw a console log.

Here's the sample of the on click function I tried:

```
console.log('#other_info')
    $("#other_info").click(function(){
        if(!$(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            console.log('yes its checked')
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('no its not!!')
        }
    })
```

this form uses iCheck custom plugin for checkboxes so a normal click or change function will not work.
done fixing the problem by using the custom function provided from ichecked

Comment: The event is working as expected when clicking:)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `click` listener in such case, but the `change` listener. I believe it's much more efficient to use.

Here is a code snippet as a quick takeaway ([working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkbctrlll/6k8r5zp2/5/)):

```
document.querySelector('#wrapped').addEventListener('change', function(event) { 
  const allClicked = this.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')
  console.log(allClicked)

  console.log(`Chief, I am clicked: ${event.target}!`) // Show what is currently being clicked
})
```

Also you can read more on the subject in my similar response here:
[How to count every checked checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725969/how-to-count-every-checked-checkboxes/55786053#55786053)

Here's a more complex fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mkbctrlll/yak4oqj9/159/

Inside you have 3 possible ways to solve your issue. Hope this helps

Comment: the script you provide triggers when an input or dropdown is clicked but when i tried to clicked a checkbox it does not trigger..

Comment: Lion please be more specific, checbox is an input. Can you update your question with the snippet of your real HTML structure?

Comment: Maybe you are having some custom made checkboxes there, that are using in example labels instead of system checkbox input? I need more viable data to help you. Too many possible options. 

Best if you could make a JSfiddle.

If non of the above is possible, can you at least provide me a DOM screenshot?

Comment: thats what im thinking also so im currently looking for the custom script for the checkbox since the onchange/onclick works on input text or select..

Comment: Then you should redefine your question, as it does not include asking about custom structure input. In normal case my answer should do the trick with ease.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Change instead of click

```
   $('#other_info').change(function() {
        if(this.checked) {

             console.log('yes its checked')
        }
      else
         {
     console.log('no its not!!')
         }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

since my form is using a custom checkbox plugin a normal change/click function will not work.

didn't know that this form was using a custom checkbox plugin so i didn't include it on my first question.

so

instead of using this function:

```
$('#other_info').on('change', function(event) {
    var checkboxChecked = $(this).is(':checked');

    if(checkboxChecked) {
        alert("checked");      
    }else{
        alert("un-checked");
    }
});
```

i use this function instead:

```
$('#other_info').on('ifChanged', function(event) {
    var checkboxChecked = $(this).is(':checked');

    if(checkboxChecked) {
        alert("checked");
    }else{
        alert("un-checked");
    }
});
```