# jquery selected how to select Checked checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In a html table I have a checkboxes colums with the following markup:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="selection_2012-10-01-LIN-C" class="selections" name="selection_checkbox" disabled="disabled">
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="selection_2012-10-01-ADE-C" class="selections" name="selection_checkbox">
```

On button click I need to validate if any of check boxes is selected, I m using the following code for that and getting `false`:

```
var selectedLots = $('input[name^="selection_checkbox"]').prop("checked");
```

Requriement is to get count of selected checkboxes or `true`, please guide me how select this.

Thanks

Comment: and [Check if checkbox is checked with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2204250/218196)

Comment: and [How to count check-boxes using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8011556/218196)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"Requriement is to get count of selected checkboxes"**

```
var count = $('input[name^="selection_checkbox"]:checked').length;
```

**"or `true`"**

```
var anyChecked = $('input[name^="selection_checkbox"]:checked').length > 0;
// OR
var anyChecked = $('input[name^="selection_checkbox"]').is(':checked');
```

More information in the doco:

- [`.length` property](http://api.jquery.com/length/)
- [`.is()` method](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use .is()

```
if(!$('input[name^="selection_checkbox"]').is(':checked')){
    //none of those are checked
}
```